# A delicate way to manage a vector of Object

Tags: c++, vector, coding-style

I am trying to manage a vector of Objects for class A.

Class A has a static std::map which maps its internal entity to its 'this' pointer on it's constructor, which looks like

```
std::map< id,A *> idmap;
```

I am aware that vector does a deep_copy while doing a push_back(). So creating an object, and the pushing into the vector is calling the constructor twice, so it would be calling the mapping procedure twice. And I'm not happy with this.

A solution to this problem may be using a vector of pointer rather that vector of objects, but I'm little bit worried about the memory leak problem that I could somehow make a mistake on it because there are lots of spots that this object(of Class A) is being referred.

So, what might be the delicate way to manage in this case? Is using vector of pointers the only proper solution?

Comment: Please show complete code. Where's the vector?

Comment: Have you looked at `emplace_back`?  Instead of constructing an object then calling `push_back` you can tell the vector to construct it in place.  You still need to be careful about the id entry in that `map` when `vector` needs to move all the objects to increase capacity.  But that can be covered with correct move semantics in the object.

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr>`. Solves your copy and memory leak concerns.

Comment: If you need access to these pointers outside of your class by other resources you could use `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<YourObject>>` If this class will be the sole owner where no other class or object has access to it then you can use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<YourObject>>`

Comment: @JSF Normally move semantics would be FTW here but there's a peculiar thing going on in this case where the op is mapping the `this` pointer of each class instance somehow, and the primary temptation seems to be in avoiding erasing and inserting redundantly. So for this kind of case, probably the ideal solution is `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>` -- `unique_ptr` instead of `shared_ptr` assuming we translate whatever he was doing originally as closely as possible.

Comment: @lke The question was whether pointers were the only proper solution.  So it was helpful to mention `unique_ptr` eliminates the major concern with pointers.  But updating a `map` is not an overwhelming concern.  `emplace_back` saves the initial extra map update.  If an accurate `reserve` is possible, it avoids the other extra updates.  Otherwise, the other extra updates might cost less than the extra indirection.  So using `unique_ptr` is just one choice.